# How to get the highest value per category in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe called *movie_df* that has more than 3000 values of **title, score, and rating.**
Titles are unique. Scores are 0.0 - 10.0. Ratings are either PG-13, G, R, or X.
They are sorted by their rating, then ascending score.

I want to find the highest rated title per rating. The highest rated title doesn't have an equal rating with another title.

| title | score | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| avengers | 5.4 | PG-13 |
| captain america | 6.7 | PG-13 |
| iron man | 8.6 | PG-13 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| spiderman | 7 | R |
| daredevil | 8.2 | R |
| deadpool | 10 | R |

Expected output:
PG-13 : Iron Man,
R : Deadpool

I don't want to use a loop to find the highest rated title.

I tried:

```
movie_df.sort_values(by=['rating', 'score'], inplace=True) # sort by rating, score
print(movie_df.to_string()) # to show dataframe
movie_df.groupby('rating').max()
```

It shows me the correct highest score, but the title is wrong. It shows me the max title too, but I don't want that. I want to know the title associated with the highest score.

Here is the actual data I'm using with its highest rated titles:
[Rated G Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPcvk.png), [NC-17 Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOYKC.png), [PG Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWe0q.png), [PG-13 Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE1CA.png), [R Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhDFd.png)

And the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNbVo.png):
[Rated G output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGzDI.png), [PG Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uboCW.png), [PG-13 Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USYJg.png), [R Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZHvf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
movie_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

m=max(movie_df['score'])

print(movie_df['rating'][list(movie_df['score']).index(m)])
```

I think you can also use `groupby()` and `agg()`

Comment: it shows me an error: 'Int64Index' object is not callable. Scores are float, ratings and titles are string, indices are int.

Comment: @LoraneBernadethFausto I updated my answer, now it should work

Comment: It's giving me an index error, so I was looking around and saw that my ratings are actually dtype('O'). Could this be why it's not working?

Comment: My `movie_df.groupby('rating').max()` code is working, but it also gets the max title for each rating. I want to get only the max score, with the associated title with that score.

Comment: @lowrain try `movie_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` instead of `movie_df.reset_index()`

Comment: @lowrain you can also try `movie_df[movie_df['score']==max(movie_df['score'])]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249751/discussion-between-khaled-dellal-and-lowrain).

Comment: It's outputting **R**, which is the highest score from the whole dataset, not what I want to do though. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your data isn't actually sorted right, that's why you're getting the wrong title but the right score.

Try `movie_df.groupby('rating').idxmax()` and check if you're getting the right index.

Comment: It is the right index. Just the title isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you want is highest score per rating, you can group each rating by highest score in this way:

```
data = [['avengers', 5.4 ,'PG-13'],
['captain america', 6.7, 'PG-13'],
['spiderman', 7,    'R'],
['daredevil', 8.2, 'R'],
['iron man', 8.6, 'PG-13'],
['deadpool', 10, 'R']]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['title', 'score', 'rating']) 
# Method 1 using lambda function
df = df.groupby('rating').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('score', ascending = False).head(1))
print(df.reset_index(drop=True))

# Method 2 
df = df.sort_values('score', ascending = False).groupby('rating').head(1)
print(df.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output1:

```
      title  score rating
0  iron man    8.6  PG-13
1  deadpool   10.0      R
```

Output2:

```
      title  score rating
0  deadpool   10.0      R
1  iron man    8.6  PG-13
```

Comment: I want to know which movie has the highest score per rating. If I change it to: movie_df.groupby(['rating'])['score'].max() , it shows me the correct values, but I want to know which title scored that. How can I make the title show?

Comment: just add column name argument `title` to the groupby method as I put it in the code.

Comment: I added it `movie_df.groupby(['rating','title'])['score'].max()` but it didn't show me the max value. It just grouped the data by rating, then title, with its respecting scores.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I think this should work.

Comment: Your code doesn't get the max value. My `movie_df.groupby('rating').max()` code is working, but it also gets the max title for each rating. I want to get only the max score, with the associated title with that score.

Comment: @lowrain Bro I found solution for your problem check the updated code :)

Comment: It gives the right title as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. This code outputs the highest scored title per rating.

```
movie_df["rank"] = movie_df.groupby("rating")["score"].rank("dense", ascending=False)
movie_df[movie_df["rank"]==1.0][['title','score']]
```

It uses the rank function from pandas.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html

Comment: Good, Also check my solution without rank it will give you same result.